# MonoTouch Equivalent to Titanium's backgroundLeftCap, backgroundTopCap for Buttons, Views?

Tags: xamarin.ios, titanium

In Appcelerator's Titanium, if you create a button object with Ti.UI.Button (or any view), you have these two properties

- backgroundLeftCap
- backgroundTopCap

which allow you to set the number of pixels of the outer edge of the image to remain static while the rest of the inside of the image is "stretched" to fill the button/views's background.

Is there an equivalent way to do this is in Xamarin's MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS's UIImage supports being resized.

Load your image:

```
 var image = UIImage.FromFile ("foo.png");
```

Stretch it:

```
 var resizableImage = image.CreateResizableImage (new UIEdgeInsets (top, left, bottom, right));
```

You can use the resulting image in any place that takes a UIImage and the region described by top/left/bottom/right will be resized, while the corners described will be kept as they are and the sides stretched.

In some versions of iOS the above will crash with some parameters (see http://openradar.appspot.com/11411000), so you can use instead:

```
 var resizableImage = image.StretchableImage (leftCap, topCap);
```

What is nice about them is that images that are created for resizing are actually resized by the GPU, so they come at a low cost.

Comment: When you ask a question about MonoTouch and the founder of Mono answers it, you accept it an upvote it.

Comment: I tried the CreateResizableImage method, and had a crash on the device (simulator worked fine), so I thought I would try the alternative (image.StretechableImage), but I get an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error with that. Any ideas?